# Login Failed in openSUSE Tumbleweed

Tags: linux, kde, opensuse, plasma, bugs

Login Failed.When I turn on my laptop I login to openSUSE Tumbleweed with same username and password, my screen shows message "login failed" I do't know how to fix it when i log in as root it work and can login to my desktop but My main User cannot.I'am newbie in linux can anyone help me please?I use desktop environment KDE Plasma.

Comment: `I login to openSUSE Tumbleweed with same username and password` ... same as what? what is your `main User`? How did you set up this user?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you have misspeled password when creating user during installation. Here are the steps to set desired password to this user.

1. Login as root
2. Run `yast`
3. In "Security and Users" section open "User and group management" (captions can be slightly different)
4. In first tab of new window you have list users, select your main User and click "Edit"
5. You now can set desired password for this user.

As a side note. In form where you can change password there is also tab with password options. It may be worth checking if everything there is as you want it to be.